# Publising .Net MVC application with Matlab inside to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, matlab, matlab-compiler

In my ASP.Net mvc 5 application I use MWArray.dll and a matlab function that I generated .dll via Matlab's Library Compiler.

Everything works fine on localhost, but on VDS I rented there is a problem

The exception throwed with the message of "The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray' threw an exception."

Inner exception is

"The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception."

One more Inner Exception is

"Unable to load DLL 'mclmcrrt9_0_1.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

And after I change the dll's with native versions, I get

"Unable to load DLL 'mclmcrrt9_0_1.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Error.

here is the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays; 
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using average; //dll that generated via Matlab Compiler SDK

namespace EleDeneme.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string[] foo;
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (MWNumericArray matrix1 = new MWNumericArray(new double[20]))
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
                    {
                        if (i % 3 == 0)
                        {
                            matrix1[1, i] = rnd.Next(100);
                            continue;
                        }
                        matrix1[1, i] = rnd.Next(10);
                    }
                    using (average.DenemeClass deneme = new DenemeClass())
                    {
                        using (MWArray res = deneme.average(matrix1))
                        {
                            //for (int i = 0; i < res.NumberOfElements; i++)
                            //{
                            var asdf = res.ToArray();
                            foo = asdf.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
                            foreach (var item in foo)
                            {
                                result += item + " ";
                            }
                            Response.Write(result);
                            //}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = ex.Message;
                Response.Write(result);
            }


            return View();
        }


    }
}
```

the average.dll is a matlab functions compiled version for .net . Also here is the MATLAB code,

```
function y = average(x)
if ~isvector(x)
    error('Input must be a vector')
end
y = sum(x)/length(x); 
end
```

before all your answers, I have installed Matlab Compiler Runtime that compatiable with Matlab R2016a to the VDS's C:\Program Files\MATLAB...

I changed IIS applicationpool and my aplications configurations as

[IIS 32bit disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMMqP.png)

but still I got the exception same as the exception first time I published to the server.

[LocalHost, working Fine (19.9 is my matlab functions output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Fbm.png)

Comment: Can you modify `result = ex.Message;` to display complete message, inner exception and stack traces in view page? The problem often originated from different architecture between development and production machine, where C# project architecture should follow Matlab Compiler Runtime version (32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Iwill now try this and post here on 10 minutes. thank you for your comment.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto first innerexception was "The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception. " and the recursive inner exception was (ex.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.Message;)  "Unable to load DLL 'mclmcrrt9_0_1.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) "

Comment: Which kind of architecture being used in both your machine and VDS (x86/x64)? Try running dependency walker on related references (especially `MWArray.dll`). If it returns something like `Modules with different CPU types were found`, ensure that PATH environment variable is correctly set and all DLL dependencies have same architecture with C# project assemblies in VDS side.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I changed the dll's with native versions. Then I changed the permissions for accessing matlab runtimes dll's and exception changed as "Unable to load DLL 'mclmcrrt9_0_1.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"